# How do I use a relative path to load my images for my website using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, path, webpack, loader

I am trying to put together a portfolio website to deploy and having some difficulty setting it up such that I can pull images from the project directory relative to my .scss file and relative to various .js files within the project. I am not good at webpack, I followed a boilerplate setup to get it working but didn't really learn it. In order to get the images to work, I have to pull them absolutely from the location on my computer. This won't work when I try to deploy it right?

I need to implement a background image in my scss file (url('')) and many images within react component called Portfolio-Piece.

I do have resolve-url-loader and sass-loader installed. Here is my webpack config...

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass", 'resolve-url','sass?sourceMap']},
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!resolve-url' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: /\.(jpg|png)$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Bonus points if someone can ELI5 What is the root when using webpack? Where is the relative path from? index.js? index.html?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `resolve-url-loader` has to be before the `sass-loader` in your config. You have the sass loader twice: `sass` and `sass?sourceMap`. I would try to change your first loader to the following: (remove the first sass)

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']},
```

In my projects, I like adding the background image styles as an inline-style on my react component and using a `require` statement. Here is an example:

```
var PortfolioPiece = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div
        className="wrapper"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('./my-img.png')})` }}
      > 
    );
  }
});
```

The `require('./my-img.png')` call will be resolved to the url where this image lives.

**Side note:** You mix double and single apostrophes in your code. You should stick to one or the other.